# Search part of string angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am trying to search in a string specifically in names and surnames, for example, mys string "oscar daniel gomez lopez" i need search "oscar gomez" or "oscar lopez" or "oscar"

i have this fuction but search lineal

```
if(that.removeAccents(String(elem[that.dash_keys[i]])).toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1){
     find = true;
     break;
}
```

the result of this fuction is

- string "oscar daniel gomez lopez" search "oscar gomez" i get false text
- string "oscar daniel gomez lopez" search "oscar daniel" i get true text
- string "oscar daniel gomez lopez" search "oscar lopez" i get false

Thanks

Comment: Are you expecting true in all search cases?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think I really understood what you want. Can you be more precise ?
About your function, I think  String.prototype.includes() do what you want

Comment: String.prototype.includes() will return the same result as he is getting right now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite understand what you want, but if you want to return true regardless of the position, each first name/last name, try this:

```
if(val.toLowerCase().split(' ').every(name=>that.removeAccents(String(elem[that.dash_keys[i]])).toLowerCase().includes(name)))
{
    find = true;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```js
  findInSentence(originalSentence: string, wordsToSearchFor: string): boolean {
    const wordsToArray = wordsToSearchFor.split(' ');
    return wordsToArray.every(word => originalSentence.toLowerCase().includes(word.toLowerCase()));
  }
```